# Reducing one item in one database table and adding it to another table

Tags: java, mysql

I am creating a library program,where when a student borrows a book,it is removed from the library table and added to the borrowed books table. My query gives me an exception of atleast one parameter to the current statement os uninitialized

```
private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{
        Connection con=CreateDB.getConnection();
         String query3="insert into borrowedbooks values(?,?,?,?,?)";
         PreparedStatement statement=con.prepareStatement(query3);
         statement.setString(1, regNo.getText());
         statement.setString(2, names.getText());
         String value3=sClass.getSelectedItem().toString();
         statement.setString(3, value3);
         statement.setString(4, ((JTextField)date.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
         statement.setString(5, title.getText());


         statement.execute();

         String query4="update bookentry set copies=copies-1 where title=?";
         Statement st=con.createStatement();
         st.executeUpdate(query4);


         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Book lent Successfully");
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is poor design. Rethink your approach

Answer (score -1):

In this LOC

```
String query3="insert into borrowedbooks values(?,?,?,?,?)";
```

You have 5 parameters and you are filling them out 1 by 1 in the following LOC's

```
     statement.setString(1, regNo.getText());
     statement.setString(2, names.getText());
     String value3=sClass.getSelectedItem().toString();
     statement.setString(3, value3);
     statement.setString(4, ((JTextField)date.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
     statement.setString(5, title.getText());
```

But in the Update query, you also have a parameter but you are not adding any value into it. This is the reason which is causing the issue. Use the previous already created statement and no need to create another. The statement you are trying to run is called prepared statement. Try running the below written code.

```
String query4="update bookentry set copies=copies-1 where title=?";
statement=con.prepareStatement(query4);
statement.setString(1, title.getText());
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score -1):

this design is a poor design. please redesign the database structure. example is given below. if some student get a book, related student id, book id and date add to the borrowed_book table as a new record

[image]

Comment: This isn't a code review. You should head over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com if you want to review code.